# Pass optional arrgument Laravel 5.8, cron job

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

```
protected $signature = 'do_command {import=false}';
public function handle(){
    $import= $this->argument('import');

    if($import){
        // do something else
    }

}
```

and I am using it in the controller and NOT only:

```
    $command = 'do_command';
    $option = null;
    if($import){
        $option = 'import';
    }
    Artisan::call($command, [$option]);
```

The problem is, it doesn't matter, if `$import` in the controller is `true/false`, if statement is always executed and `$this->argument('import')` is always true in `handle` method, even if I call `Artisan::call($command)` without second argument.

Comment: The default value is (string) "false" not actually false. Which means it will be true inside your if statement. I think you should also pass the option as ['import' => true] not ['import']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining the default value of `import` as `false`, which would be a `string`. Therefore, the if condition in your command will always be `true`:

```
if ($import) {
    // 
}
```

What you could do is change the signature to have the import option as [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#defining-input-expectations).

```
protected $signature = 'command:name {import?}';
```

Then in your controller:

```
Artisan::call($command, [
    'import' => $import,
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

First define the options as parameters.

```php
class GenerateApiToken extends Command
{
    protected $signature = "apitoken:generate
    {--id= : A description of the option}
    {--value= : A description of the option}
    ";

    public function handle()
    {
        $id = $this->option('id');
        $value = $this->option('value');
    ...
```

Then grab them using `$this->option()`

To use them in a call from the application:

```php
Artisan::call('apitoken:generate', ['id' => $id]);
```

Edit: I think the reason yours doesn't work is because the array you're passing the command in the second parameter of `::call()` is not an associative array with the keynames representing options.

Comment: `import argument doesn't exists`. I have tried and with `--` - `--import argument doesn't eexists` or without `--`